# Scrapy pass object from pipeline to Spider

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am working on a scraping project using scrapy. I plan to implement a cache (dictionary) of the items being scraped by using some of the item properties (depending upon some criteria) and this cache will eventually be stored as a file on the disk. When scrapy starts, I can use the spider_closed function in pipelines.py to load the cache from the file and dump the modified cache back to the file while scrapy is closing (using spider_closed function). While the items are being scraped, the cache will be modified. Items be added to the cache if the items are unique. In pipelines.py, I can create a variable mycache to load the cache from the cache file:

```
mycache = load_from(cache_file)
```

But I don't know how to pass mycache from pipelines.py to mySpider.py so that they both share a single copy of mycache.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CustomPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self, spider):
        # the spider now contains a cache object
        spider.mycache = TheCacheObject()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.spider)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        spider.mycache = do_your_thing
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're saying is possible but it's bad design. I don't know what actions you're going to take according to this cache, but whatever it is, it should be done inside that specific pipeline. One concept of pipelines is that every pipeline step depends potentially on previous steps *but not from any steps after it*. It's a little bit like saying I'm going to decide only after I know the future. Not good! Additionally it's good design practise to be able to disable a pipeline stage and the rest of the system to be working. Especially in your case, where what you do is caching... well... caches should always be performance optimisations and not affect functionality. How will you be able to disable the cache pipeline without breaking your poor spider(s)?

Anyway - I understand that pipelines process only `Item`s and one possible reason that might make you want to feed an `Item` cache back to your spider is because you want to take actions or affect `Request`s. That's what [Spider Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html)s are there for. They can process e.g. drop both `Item`s and `Request`s. I would expect that if your cache can't be fully implemented with a spider, it will be able to be implemented fully with a [Spider Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html).

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
       for x in result:
           if not isinstance(x, Request):
               # Pass-throug all items
               yield x
           else:
               if x.url not in self.urls_cache:
                   yield x

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'project.middlewares.MyMiddleware: 100,
}
```